# Routinely changing Vista timezone back and forth during travel - bad?

Tags: time-zone

I travel for work routinely and am often in a different time zone than my home timezone for days at a time.  Is there a drawback to routinely changing the timezone of my Vista PC back and forth each week as I travel?  Btw, it's normally only one or two timezones away from my home timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem changing the time zone frequently.

The only time changing the system time becomes a problem is when you are connected to a domain and you have active Kerberos tickets issued, as the time on the ticket must match the time on the Kerberos Key Distribution Center (usually a domain controller). Even in this instance, changing the time zone won't matter, as it is just an offset. This only happens when changing the actual time. This is why there is no easy way to change time on a domain-joined PC, as it syncs with the domain controllers by default.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with it, but have you considered [displaying multiple timezones](http://www.dq.winsila.com/tips-tricks/how-to-display-multiple-timezones-in-vista.html)?

> - Right click on the time in the System Tray.
> - Select Adjust Date/Time
> - Click on the Additional Clocks tab.
> - Here you can create clocks for one or two extra time zones.
>
> Although Vista will still show only
>   your local time in the System Tray,
>   when you put the mouse cursor over the
>   time display, the additional clocks
>   will appear. If you click on the time,
>   you will see all the clocks in the
>   analogue style.